# printing the next line from file c coding

Tags: c, file

My code is this. I am reading a file, comparing the word entered by user from data in file and then want to print the next two words from file. How can I do that?

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        int main()
        {
           //Open the file for reading
                    FILE *in = fopen("data.txt", "r");
           char str[]="file1.txt";
           //fgets buffer
           char buffer[100];

         //Pieces of string tokenized
        char * stringPiece;

         //int for comparing strings
           int compare=2;


        //While loop. Getting lines from file
        while ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL ){
             fgets(buffer, 100, in);
            // printf("%s\n", buffer);

         stringPiece = strtok (buffer,",");
             while (stringPiece != NULL){


          printf("%s\n",stringPiece);
          compare=strcmp(stringPiece,str);

          if (compare==0){printf("HELP");}

          //printf("%s\n",stringPiece);
          stringPiece = strtok (NULL, " ");
      }
   }
         //Close file
                fclose(in);

                       return 0;
}
```

I can find the word in file same as what user entered but unable to print the next two words from file. File name is data.txt.

Code formatted to be legible (use `vim` and `=%` on the open brace of the `main()` function, mostly).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Open the file for reading
    FILE *in = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char str[]="file1.txt";
    //fgets buffer
    char buffer[100];

    //Pieces of string tokenized
    char * stringPiece;

    //int for comparing strings
    int compare=2;

    //While loop. Getting lines from file
    while ( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL ){
        fgets(buffer, 100, in);
        // printf("%s\n", buffer);

        stringPiece = strtok (buffer,",");
        while (stringPiece != NULL){

            printf("%s\n",stringPiece);
            compare=strcmp(stringPiece,str);

            if (compare==0){printf("HELP");}

            //printf("%s\n",stringPiece);
            stringPiece = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    //Close file
    fclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since your problem is defined in terms of words rather than lines, you'll probably find it quite a bit easier to read a word at a time instead of a line at a time.

Comment: I always wondered why it was called a *space* bar ...

Comment: Can you write your code with some comments? For this code, mention:
1) Where are you fetching list of words?
2) What is the original string with you want to compare with?
Also good indentation will also help others to read your code.

Comment: Also I would suggest to do it by yourself instead of asking for others to help because this should be a very basic code.

Comment: oke i confess i dont know the basics but i need help  can u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample of find the word and next two words get

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char userInputWord[]="file1.txt";
    char readFromFileData[]="c:,file1.txt,date,size";
    char *tokenPtr,*nextFirstWord,*nextSecondWord;

    tokenPtr=strtok(readFromFileData, ",");
    for(;tokenPtr != NULL;tokenPtr=strtok(NULL, ",")){
        if(0!=strcmp(tokenPtr, userInputWord))
            continue;//skip word
        //find it!
        printf("%s\n",tokenPtr);
        nextFirstWord = strtok(NULL, ",");
        nextSecondWord = strtok(NULL, ",");
        if(nextFirstWord)
            printf("first word is \"%s\"\n", nextFirstWord);
        else
            fprintf(stderr,"first word is nothing!\n");
        if(nextSecondWord)
            printf("second word is \"%s\"\n", nextSecondWord);
        else
            fprintf(stderr,"second word is nothing!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```